# On what SE site should I post a Chrome (browser) usability question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a question about how to use Chrome profiles/persons.

On what SE site should I post such a question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) looks like the right fit in general.

If you're on Mac, [Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com) is an option, as is [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) if you're on that platform. (Although [Super User](http://superuser.com) is ok for those too.)

If you're using Chrome on Android, ask over at [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com).

[Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) doesn't fit, it is for using web applications, not the browser you're viewing them from.

Comment: Thanks. Posted on SU - http://superuser.com/questions/909506/how-to-switch-to-a-non-visible-profile-person-in-chrome